# How to use STA mode in PowerShell 1.0?

Tags: powershell, sta, powershell-1.0

I'm very awkward in PowerShell and I use it only at home for my own simple tasks under my Windows XP where no available upgrade to PS2. Next test show that my PowerShell 1.0 use MTA mode by default.

```
[threading.thread]::CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()
```

And such call like...

```
PowerShell.exe –STA c:\scripts\file.ps1
```

...always fail with error:

> Missing expression after unary operator '-'. At line:1 char:2
>   + -S <<<< TA c:\scripts\file.ps1

Looks like my PS1 not recognize –STA switch. What I do wrong? Is there any way at all to run my script in STA mode in PS1?

Comment: here you can download powershell 2.0 for XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929/en-us

Comment: here you can find something usefully for sta in v1.0 : http://get-powershell.com/post/2008/11/07/Single-Threaded-Apartment-in-PowerShell-V1.aspx

Comment: @C.B. - PS2 not available for 64bit XP (my case), I s'd mention this, but many thanks for your comments, you confirm my fears that I'm in big trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The dash character before STA in your command is "–" Unicode U+2013 "En Dash" where it should be "-" Unicode U+002D "Hyphen-Minus". You can try it with this JavaScript function in your browser console (F12):

```
function getHex(character) {
    return "0x" + character.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
}

getHex('–'); // 0x2013
getHex('-'); // 0x2d
```

Perhaps you have copied it from a web page or a PDF or Word document. Try to type the command instead of copy/paste and it will work.

New versions of PowerShell will recognize both characters for dash.

Comment: While your response is true, it's not why PowerShell v1 fails to start with the -sta switch... PowerShell v1 does not support the -sta switch.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Sta -File c:\scripts\file.ps1